# Passing a dropdown selected value to a contorller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm playing around in an MVC application and am trying to figure out something that seems pretty straight forward.

I have a `Index.cshtml` file in my `Views/Home/` folder that is pretty simple (below)

Index view

```
...
    <div>
        Search
        @Html.DropDownList("selection", MyProject.Util.Lists.GetMyList(), "Select One")
        @Html.ActionLink("Search", "Index", "Search", new { st = xxx }, null)
    </div>
...
```

I also have a Search controller that needs to take a "st" value and looks like this

```
public class SearchController : Controller
{
    // GET: Search
    public ActionResult Index(string st)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        List<Report> filteredReports = db.Reports.Where(r => r.Tag == st).ToList();

        return View(filteredReports);
    }
}
```

What I'm not sure of how do is grab what ever value is selected from the drop down and add that to my `Html.ActionLink` where I just have 'xxx' now.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the link usuallly does a new GET request to the href attribute value of the link. It will not send any data from your form.

You need to use javascript and hijack the click event on the link and append the selected option value from the SELECT element as querystring to that and send it.

So give an id to the link which you can use later to wireup the click event

```
@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Index", "Search", null, new {@id="search"})
```

And the javascript

```
$(function(){

  $("#search").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href=$(this).attr("href")+"?st="+$("#selection").val();
  });

});
```

Another option is to use the form submit. Wrap your select element inside a form and have a submt button which sends the form to the action method. This method does not need javascript. But **your select input element name should match with your parameter name**.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Search",FormMethod.Get))
{ 
   <div>
    Search
    @Html.DropDownList("st", MyProject.Util.Lists.GetMyList(), "Select One")
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
   </div>
}
```

If you do not prefer to have button, but need the link element, you can use javascript to submit the form (*like we did in the first approach*). With this approach you do not need to manually append the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call a AJAX POST call to your controller which store selected value, and then when your action link event fire get stored value from there.

**AJAX:**

```
$.ajax(
{
    url:your url,
    data:{"st":dropdown selected value},
    type:"post"
});
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string st=TempData["st"].ToString();
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    List<Report> filteredReports = db.Reports.Where(r => r.Tag == st).ToList();

    return View(filteredReports);
}

public void SetSt(string st)
{
    TempData["st"] = st;
}
```